# Uncaught TypeError Cannot change property of 'changeSelection' of undefined Magento 1.9 bundle product

Tags: magento-1.9

My bundled products aren't working properly.

On loading the product page it already goes wrong with the following error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reloadPrice' of undefined

When i select an option from the drop-down box, the amount field stays grayed out and i get an error in the console (Google Chrome) stating:

Uncaught TypeError Cannot change property of 'changeSelection' of undefined

The HTML from the amount field has the property disabled=""disabled", I guess this is supposed to change on making your selection thus enabling you to change the amount for the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution..

It's caused by our custom theme not adding the new product_options.js file.

In your theme layout file (either local.xml or catalog.xml) and add the following js under the **catalog_product_view**

***varien/product_options.js***